# combine rows of results into one in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting the following data in postrges

```
id|    count1     count2
12     3          0
12     0          2
```

But I want the combined result

Query from which I am getting above result

```
SELECT
    date_part( 'day', t1.requested_datetime ) AS requested_day,
    CASE
      WHEN date_part ( 'hour', t1.requested_datetime ) >= 0 AND date_part ( 'hour', t1.requested_datetime ) <= 11 THEN count ( date_part ( 'day', t1.requested_datetime ) )
      ELSE 0
    END AS count_am,
    CASE
      WHEN date_part ( 'hour', t1.requested_datetime ) > 11 AND date_part ( 'hour', t1.requested_datetime ) <= 23 THEN count ( date_part ( 'day', t1.requested_datetime ) )
      ELSE 0
    END AS count_pm
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    date_part ( 'month', t1.requested_datetime ) = 11
    AND date_part ( 'year', t1.requested_datetime ) = 2013
GROUP BY
    requested_day,
    date_part ( 'hour', t1.requested_datetime )
ORDER BY
    date_part ( 'day', t1.requested_datetime )
```

**Expected result**

```
id    count1   count2
12    3        2
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: actually it could be interesting how did you get this data. Looks liks you've tried to pivot your data

Comment: I have added the query from which I am getting the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, 
       sum(count1) as count1,
       sum(count2) as count2
from your_table
group by id
```